# Duplicate excel rows as many times as number in a cell in the row & rename a cell in the duplicate row

Tags: excel, vbscript, duplicate-data

I would like to duplicate a line many times:

```
WO      Desc    Quantity    Start       End         Sublot

210000  xxxyyy  2460        2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400
```

The number of duplicated rows would be Quantity / Sublot + 1
WO cell would be renamed, to 210000_1, _2, etc depending on the number of rows.
Quantity would be equal to sublot, last line would be remainder (60 in this case)

```
WO          Desc    Quantity    Start       End         Sublot

210000_1    xxxyyy  400         2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400

210000_2    xxxyyy  400         2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400

210000_3    xxxyyy  400         2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400

210000_4    xxxyyy  400         2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400

210000_5    xxxyyy  400         2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400

210000_6    xxxyyy  400         2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400

210000_7    xxxyyy  60          2014 07 31  2014 08 05  400
```

Would anyone have a piece of code for this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need vb?
Just calculate the number of rows (round(2460/400,0) and create a result worksheet. The row() function and the concat & operator and a simple if clause to render empty rows at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately my Excel is in german.
on the left side the result, on the right the formulas
(translation:

```
wenn=if
runden=round
zeile=line/row
rest=modulo/remainder of a division

; is used to separate parameters the english version uses , afaik
```

)

Hope it helps

[image: Excel Solution]

Comment: Thank you very much! Helps a lot, although I need to adopt it, as my sheet contains 4000 lines and each one needs to be split.

Comment: I can't get it to insert as many empty rows as needed automatically... so it will be a lot of manual work.thats why I think I will need a VBScript in the end.

Comment: So basically I am trying to automate this, so that I do not need to do it manually for a base of 4000 lines that would be like 2x000 lines in the end... thats a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK, did it:

```
Sub insertrows()
Dim x As Long
Dim split As Integer
Dim rowstepper As Integer
Dim currow As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim remain As Integer
Dim sublot As Integer
Dim sublotcount As Integer
rowstepper = 1
currow = 1
split = Cells(rowstepper, 7).Value
total = Cells(rowstepper, 2).Value
sublot = Cells(rowstepper, 8).Value
remain = total
sublotcount = Cells(rowstepper, 7).Value
Do
split = Cells(rowstepper, 7).Value
total = Cells(rowstepper, 2).Value
sublot = Cells(rowstepper, 8).Value
remain = total
sublotcount = Cells(rowstepper, 7).Value
For x = 1 To split
    Rows(x + rowstepper).Resize(1).Insert
    Cells(x + rowstepper, 1) = Cells(rowstepper, 1).Value & "_" & x
    total = total - sublot
    remain = remain - sublot
    If total > remain - (sublotcount - 1) * sublot Then
        Cells(x + rowstepper, 3) = sublot
    Else
        Cells(x + rowstepper, 3) = sublot + remain
    End If
    sublotcount = sublotcount - 1
    currow = rowstepper + split + 1
Next x
    rowstepper = currow
Loop While Not Cells(currow, 1).Value = ""
End Sub
```